# Compare A Drawcircle Function With An Image In Matlab

Tags: templates, matlab, matching, geometry

I use

```
rectangle ('position', [0, 0, 50, 50], 'curvature', [1, 1])
```

to draw a circle on an image. The circle is smaller then the image and I need to multiply the cirkel values (pixel values should be 1 on edge and zero everywhere else, binary circle) with every possible location of the image. It is a sort of template matching, but instead of using a template to calculate correlation, I want to use a circlefunction cause it's faster then loading thousands of templates.

Any ideas of how i can make the circle function have binary values and multiply it with parts of the image?

I hope my formulation is good enough

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a circle as a filter, then you don't want to *draw* it, do you?  What you want is a matrix of 1s and 0s, and to multiply this by every 50x50 rectangular portion of the image.  To get the matrix,

```
d = 50;
F = false(d,d);
[X Y] = meshgrid( size(F) ) - d/2;
F( round(hypot(X,Y)) == d/2 ) = true;
```

Haven't actually run this code but something like this should work.  imagesc(F) will show you what it looks like. Then you need to get your image into a matrix, and step through the tiles.